# Why does `std::is_const_v` not behave as expected?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, standards, type-traits

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
void f(T&&)
{
    cout << boolalpha << std::is_const_v<T> << endl;
    cout << boolalpha << std::is_const_v<T&&> << endl;
}

int main()
{
    const int n = 1;
    f(n);
}
```

The output is:

```
false
false
```

Here, `n` is an obvious const variable, why does `std::is_const_v` not behave as expected?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`std::is_const` is `false` when the type is a reference:

[cppreference:](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_const)

> If `T` is a reference type then `is_const<T>::value` is always false. The proper way to check a potentially-reference type for const-ness is to remove the reference: `is_const<typename remove_reference<T>::type>`

In your specific case, `T` is a forwarding reference, which will be deduced as lvalue reference when passing a lvalue argument. That's why you see the `false` in two cases.